# How to only select 2 column from the database with laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use laravel 5.1 to select records from MySQL database and break the results into pages.

Here is the method that I use to return the database results to the listall view. (This code display white screen "no errors, no results")

```
public function getIndex(){

    $accounts = DB::table('accounts')
                    ->lists('account_id','account_name')
                    ->where('client_id', '=', 7)
                    ->paginate(100);

    $name = 'Mike A';

    return view('accounts.listall', compact('accounts', 'name'));

}
```

When using this code below, it works but it returns all the column. I only want to display 2 columns.

```
public function getIndex(){

    $accounts = DB::table('accounts')
                    ->where('client_id', '=', 7)
                    ->paginate(100);

    $name = 'Mike A';

    return view('accounts.listall', compact('accounts', 'name'));

}
```

**EDITED**

This is my code after Kyle Suggestion "below"

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use App\Accounts;

class AccountsController extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex(){

        $accounts = Accounts::select('account_id', 'account_name')
                    ->where('client_id', '=', 7)
                    ->paginate(100);


        $name = 'Mike A';

        return view('accounts.listall', compact('accounts', 'name'));

    }

    public function getAccounts($id){

        return view('accounts.account')->withName('Mike A');
    }
}
```

This is my Accounts Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Accounts extends Model
{

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'accounts';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['account_id', 'account_name', 'company_code'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];
}
```

But I still get a white screen

Comment: Instead of `lists` use `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't be using `DB::table('accounts')`.  You should be using `Account::all()`.  It's just syntax though I guess.

I assume you have a table named accounts with 2 columns of that table being `account_id` and `account_name`.  That being said, your whole class should look similar to this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Account; //don't forget this so you can use it below

class AccountController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex() {
        $accounts = Account::select('account_id', 'account_name')
                    ->where('client_id', '=', 7)
                    ->paginate(100);

        $name = 'Mike A';

        return view('accounts.listall', compact('accounts', 'name'));
    }
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the App\Account class? How should it look like?

Comment: The `app\Account.php` file would be a model.  It's similar to `app\User.php` if you want an example.  It defines the table and fillable fields that way you don't have to deal with just the table directly.

Comment: Thank you. I still get a blank white screen

Comment: Blank white screens usually mean an issue with php.ini configuration.  Your memory limit may be set too low.  If you can find your php log file it may give you more information.  If you don't see the typical laravel error screen... it may not be laravel.

Comment: the page runs pretty fast, I doubt that it would be a memory limit. is there an error log file in laravel somewhere?

Comment: I don't know what us mamp. I don't think I am

Answer (score 0):

In the [Laravel Query Builder docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries), see "Specifying a Select Clause". To do what you are trying to do, you need to use the `select` method instead of the `lists` method you are using.

The `select` method allows you to specify which columns you want from the table, and returns `$this` (The Query Builder instance) so that you can chain it with more Query Builder methods like you are doing with `where` and `paginate`.

The `lists` method returns an array (see in the docs under "Retrieving A List Of Column Values"). The returned array will not have the `where` and `paginate` methods. This is what is currently killing your script and giving you the white screen.

The `lists` method should be the last method called in a chain of query builder methods. Like `get` or `paginate`, it is meant to return the results of your query in a specific way.

Comment: I have tried using select list Kyle mentioned in his answer. But I still get a white page. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I will update my question with Kyle suggestion

Comment: Calling an invalid method with query builder would still show the laravel stack trace. Not a white screen of death.

Comment: @Kyle True, good point. With the information given, It's surprising that the Laravel error page isn't showing up. Doesn't it seem like those methods would be invalid at that point, though?